# How to read and write of TFOD2 pipeline.config file by python?

Tags: python, file, tensorflow, tf.keras, object-detection-api

As you have already seen in Tensorflow objects detection they provide pipeline.config file with respect to a particular model. But there we need to manually open these config files & change the parameter by hard coding. My query is like how can I read this pipeline.config file by python & change the parameter in runtime. Please help me with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an example in the [tutorial notebook](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/colab_tutorials/eager_few_shot_od_training_tf2_colab.ipynb).

```
from object_detection.utils import config_util, save_pipeline_config

pipeline_config = 'configs/tf2/ssd_resnet50_v1_fpn_640x640_coco17_tpu-8.config'

configs = config_util.get_configs_from_pipeline_file(pipeline_config)
configs['model'].ssd.num_classes = 10 # change number of classes
```

Then, you can save:

```
save_pipeline_config(configs, 'path/to/save/dir/')
```

See the [source code](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/utils/config_util.py#L240).

Comment: Thank you so much,,, but there is another problem i am having while saving the config file ,, this is the error

Comment: File "C:\Anaconda\envs\tfod2.x\lib\site-packages\google\protobuf\text_format.py", line 187, in MessageToString
    printer.PrintMessage(message)
  File "C:\Anaconda\envs\tfod2.x\lib\site-packages\google\protobuf\text_format.py", line 428, in PrintMessage
    if (message.DESCRIPTOR.full_name == _ANY_FULL_TYPE_NAME and
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'DESCRIPTOR'

Comment: @BappyAhmed, I took the same issue with you. If you give a configs parameter as configs['model'], the method work. But this time you save only the model parameters.
save_pipeline_config(configs['model'], 'path/to/save_dir')

Answer (score 2):

The answer of @Nicolas Gervais seems to be a bit outdated.
This seems to be the fully working version right now:

```
from object_detection.utils import config_util

pipeline_config = 'configs/tf2/ssd_resnet50_v1_fpn_640x640_coco17_tpu-8.config'

configs = config_util.get_configs_from_pipeline_file(pipeline_config)
configs['model'].ssd.num_classes = 10 # change number of classes
```

After you can save your pipeline.config in the following way:

```
# Convert dictionary to pipeline_pb2.TrainEvalPipelineConfig to be able to save it 
pipeline_proto = config_util.create_pipeline_proto_from_configs(configs)
config_util.save_pipeline_config(pipeline_proto, 'path/to/save/dir/')
```

Comment: This works. But after saving the 2nd config file, its accuracy, compared to the original one, may change. For example, (original) `decay: 0.9900000095367432` is changed to `decay: 0.99`. It rounds to the nearest value.